# SQL SERVER AND HIBERNATE UPDATE DDL ISSUE

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, ddl

I've been on problems with hibernate ddl update tool and Sql Server. First of all I would like to explain that our application ddl update works normally on mysql, postgres or even oracle.

Let me explain what happens:

We created in the sqlserver users that access the same databases, however it is in different schemas, for example:

- USERS: USER1, USER2, USER3
- USER1 CONNECTS TO SCHEMA1
- USER2 CONNECTS TO SCHEMA2
- USER3 CONNECTS TO SCHEMA3

  The permissions we granted to these users are: db_datareader, db_datawriter, dbowner, public

  It works sometimes, but sometimes it doesn't

Have you guys ever experienced a problem like this?

Comment: No, I haven't. And this answer is correct ;-)